# How to get the position/index of the nth item in a list, R

Tags: r, list

I have a list of vectors, and I have written a basic for loop to iterate over the list. I am trying to write a series functions and transformations to apply to each vector that depends on the position of the vector in the list. Each vector may not be unique. Here is an example below:

```
vec1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
vec2 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
vec3 <- c(10, 11, 12, 13)

listVec <- list(vec1, vec2, vec3)

for (n in listVec){
  
  #get the position of n in the list
  #Other stuff I want to do based on position
}
```

I basically want to know if the nth vector is at the first, second, or third position in the list.

Thank you.

@missuse provided the answer in the comment below.

Restructuring the loop as follows allows me to do what I want to do:

```
for (n in seq_along(listVec)){
 
  #get the poistion of n in the list
  position<- n
  
  #get the vector correspoding to that position
  working <- listVec[[n]]
  
 
  #Other stuff I want to do based on position
}
```

Comment: ...`n in seq_along(listVec)...` and `n` will be the position, `listVec[[n]]` will be the vector

Comment: Can you show your expecetdd output

Comment: @missuse, your comment is what I'm looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `imap`, `.x` being the object and `.y` its index:

```
library(purrr)

listVec %>% imap(~list(.x,.y))

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 1


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 2


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 10 11 12 13

[[3]][[2]]
[1] 3
```

Comment: @Phil_T, did it answer your question?